# Configure Addthis URL

Tags: html, share, addthis

I use plugin addthis in share option I use the default (share web pages), but in like(facebook), twitter, and google+ I want with my definition. Here my Code :

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="float:left">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" href="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" href="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium" href="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
```

But this code not work in my web..

Answer (score 7):

Replace "href" with "addthis:url".  To specify title as well, use "addthis:title".  Full documentation can be found here:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#.UFczI6SXRuo

Here is what your code should look like:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="float:left">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" addthis:url="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" addthis:url="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium" addthis:url="http://www.website.com/"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" addthis:url="http://www.website.com"></a>
</div>
```